# simple prompt quiz javascript , pop up questions is showing all questsions

Tags: javascript

im new to programming and i keep having all questions comeup,i want the math.random  to pick 1 random question and ask it and log answer to the console but i keep getting prompted all the questions

```
var langquestion = prompt('what is the best language?');
var progquestion = prompt('how many years have you been programming?');
var drivequestion = prompt('does veronica drive good?');



var ran = Math.random() * 10;

if (ran < 3) {
    if (langquestion === 'javascript') {
        console.log('correct');
    } else {
        console.log('wrong');
    }
} else if (ran < 6 && ran > 3) {
    if (progquestion < 2) {
        console.log('keep working hard');
    } else if (progquestion > 2 && progquestion < 5) {
        console.log('your a programmer');
    } else {
        console.log('your the man');
    }
} else {
    if (drivequestion === 'yes'){
        console.log('correct');
    } else { 
        console.log('wrong');
    }
};
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you `prompt` multiple times in a row, on the first 3 lines of your code.

Since your questions have different logics to handle the answer, you could structure your code like this:

```js
var questions = [
  {
    text: 'What is the best language?',
    handler: function(answer) {
      return answer === 'javascript' ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong';
    }
  },
  {
    text: 'How many years have you been programming?',
    handler: function(answer) {
      if (answer < 2) return 'Keep working hard';
      else if (answer < 5) return 'You\'re a programmer';
      else return 'You\'re the man';
    }
  },
  {
    text: 'Does veronica drive well?',
    handler: function(answer) {
      return answer === 'yes' ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong';
    }
  }
];


var rand     = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length),
    question = questions[rand],
    answer   = prompt(question.text);

console.log(question.handler(answer));
```